# How can I find a curve based on its tangent lines?

Tags: derivatives, plane-curves

Let's say for some curve its tangent lines at every point have a property that the length of a segment within the first quarter $[0;+\infty)^2$ is exactly $C>0$.

How can such a curve be defined analytically? Maybe even in terms of $y=f(x)$.

---

Now about the tangent lines themselves. Noticeably for all $k<0$ the tangent line $y = kx - \frac{Ck}{\sqrt{k^2 + 1}}$ seems to fit the description precisely because the length of its segment within the first quarter is equal to $C$. But what to do next?

Comment: If I understand what you're describing correctly, the tangent line equation you've given doesn't fit the description. It's actually not even dimensionally consistent. $kx-\frac{Ck}{\sqrt{k^2 + 1}}$ should work though.

Comment: If $k$ denoted a *continuous function* $k(t)$, we get a continuous family of tangents, and somehow we might be able to derive the curve(s) it belongs to...

Comment: Your curve can be viewed as the [envelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_%28mathematics%29) of a family of curves. Look at the wiki page of envelop for how to find such a curve in general. In particular, look at [example 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_%28mathematics%29#Example_4) there. The curve you are after is called [astroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid), it is a special case of example 4 with parameter $\alpha = 2$.

Comment: @achillehui I think if you were to put that in an answer explaining the general method, it would be a better one than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most precise argument, but here's one way to go about it: let's take the tangent lines to have the form

$$y = kx - \frac{Ck}{\sqrt{k^2 + 1}}$$

for $k < 0$, as I mentioned in a comment. Two of these tangent lines with slopes $k$ and $k'$ intersect at the point with $x$-coordinate given by

$$kx_\text{int} - \frac{Ck}{\sqrt{k^2 + 1}} = k'x_\text{int} - \frac{Ck'}{\sqrt{k'^2 + 1}}$$

or

$$x_\text{int} = \frac{C}{(k' - k)}\biggl(\frac{k'}{\sqrt{k'^2 + 1}} - \frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2 + 1}}\biggr)$$

If the difference between these slopes is very small, $k' = k + \epsilon$, this expression simplifies to

$$x_\text{int} = \frac{C}{(k^2 + 1)^{3/2}} + O(\epsilon)$$

which tells us the $x$-coordinate of the point where two lines of similar slope intersect.

It stands to reason that if the curve we're looking for, $y = f(x)$, is not too "crazy", the points at which it is tangent to two lines converge to the intersection of those two lines as the difference between the slopes of the lines goes to zero. So in the $\epsilon\to 0$ limit, we get an expression for the slope at the convergence point:

$$f'\Biggl(\frac{C}{(k^2 + 1)^{3/2}}\Biggr) = k$$

or equivalently,

$$f'(x_\text{int}) = -\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{C}{x_\text{int}}\biggr)^{2/3}-1}$$

As [achille hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui) pointed out in the comments, the relevant solution to this differential equation is the function

$$f(x) = C\Biggl[1 - \biggl(\frac{x}{C}\biggr)^{2/3}\Biggr]^{3/2}$$

which is called an [astroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid).

[image: picture of the curve]